# What REST action should I use for Validate?

Tags: rest, url-parameters

I have a design question on REST. I need to expose a validate method as a rest resource. Let us say it looks like this

```
public ValidatedResult validate(ObjectToBeValidated object)
```

`ObjectToBeValidated` is a class that contains the actual `Object` and also some parameters concerning the validation.

When I design this as a Restful resource, which action do I use? From my understanding GET is the action that best suits this case. If that is so, how I can pass my `ObjectTobeValidated` as an object but not as URL parameters? I shy away from URL parameters because `ObjectToBeValidated` may contain a lot of properties, ending up with an URL like below which is feel is too long

```
http://localhost/rest/validate?prop1=somevalu&prop2=somevalue&prop3=something&prop11=somevalu&prop22=somevalue&prop33=something
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks
Kay

Comment: Why do you need to validate objects? What are the clients supposed to do with a validated object? Because, if the next step is to persist the object for example, you could validate the object directly in the method that handles persistence, and return a 4xx error if the object is not valid.

Comment: maybe the word validate does not correctly describe my intent here. As an example, the client will send in a request that has a player name and a sport. The resource will return a much more detailed player object (sport, team, career etc). In cases the resource might not return anything.

Comment: What you describe is not validation. That is simply GETting a resource filtered by name + sport

Comment: In our domain, our domain experts are used to calling such an operation Validate. It is almost like the client passes in not so well defined object and they get from the server the same object validated with more details added to it

Comment: "I have a player name and sport, give me the full object" would be translated to e.g. `/rest/players?name=jack&sport=baseball` That's called filtering, validation is something else entirely

Comment: I dont disagree with you, am just using the terms that are used in my domain. If it is a get in this case, like i said before am looking at more than 10 URL parameters? Is that the right way to go about it?

Comment: another usecase we have is something called address standardization. The client passes in an unformatted address, the server looks at the address, verifies it and returns back a standarized address (with much more details attahced).

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP standard allows you to use the POST method. It does not necessary need to have a side effect.

> The action performed by the POST method might not result in a resource
>   that can be identified by a URI. In this case, either 200 (OK) or 204
>   (No Content) is the appropriate response status, depending on whether
>   or not the response includes an entity that describes the result.

- [HTTP 1.1 / method definitions / POST](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

In your case you can do something like this if you want to follow the noun-verb approach Tim suggested:

```
POST /api/my/object/validator
```

Be aware that by REST the messages must be self-descriptive, so either you need a vendor MIME type or you need to add meta-data e.g. RDF to describe what this link does and what params are allowed. Otherwise we are not talking about REST, just a regular webapp.